# Regular Expression for domain from email address

Tags: .net, regex, email-address

Can anyone help me with a regular expression that will return the end part of an email address, after the @ symbol? I'm new to regex, but want to learn how to use it rather than writing inefficient .Net string functions!

E.g. for an input of "test@example.com" I need an output of "example.com".

Cheers!
Tim

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A regular expression is quite heavy machinery for this purpose. Just split the string containing the email address at the `@` character, and take the second half. (An email address is guaranteed to contain only one `@` character.)

Comment: <nerdvoice> This is not technically true as you can have multiple @ signs if and only if the @ sign is in a quoted string http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Syntax </nerdvoice>  For all intents and purposes of email address verification, a single @ sign is the splitter.

Answer (score 14):

@(.*)$

This will match with the @, then capture everything up until the end of input ($)

Comment: Thanks! I'm getting "@example.com". Can I get the value without the @?

Comment: You're probably not getting the right group. The parenthesis `(`, `)` indicate a group match, so make sure you grab the result from group with index 1, not 0 (as index #0 is always reserved for the entire expression match).

Comment: This is the correct answer as the OP specifically asked for a regex... which incidentally is what I was looking for when I arrived here :)

Answer (score 4):

This is a general-purpose e-mail matcher:

```
[a-zA-Z][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]@([a-zA-Z0-9][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z])
```

Note that it only captures the domain group; if you use the following, you can capture the part proceeding the `@` also:

```
([a-zA-Z][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])@([a-zA-Z0-9][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z])
```

I'm not sure if this meets RFC 2822, but I doubt it.

Answer (score 3):

A simple regex for your input is:

```
^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$
```

But, it can be useless when you apply for a broad and heterogeneous domains.

An example is:

```
^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.(?:[A-Z]{2}|com|org|net|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|jobs|museum)$
```

But, you can optimize that suffix domains as you need.

But for your suffix needs, you need just:

@.+$

Resources:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Comment: actually the [regex is a bit longer](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/RJBS/Email-Valid-0.182/lib/Email/Valid.pm)

Comment: I recommend this one over my solution as it is less restrictive.

Comment: Just don't forget to capture the domain into a group, as asked: `^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@([A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4})$`

Comment: And, uh, don't forget to escape those '.'s, even in characters classes.

Answer (score 3):

Wow, all the answers here are not quite right.

An email address can have as many "@" as you want, and the last one isn't necessarily the one before the domain :(

for example, this is a valid email address:

```
user@example.com(i'm a comment (with an @))
```

You'd have to be pretty mean to make that your email address though.

So first, parse out any comments at the end.

Then

```
int atIndex = emailAddress.LastIndexOf("@");
String domainPart = emailAddress.Substring(atIndex + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$input=hardiksondagar@gmail.com;
// now you want to fetch gmail from input user PHP's inbuilt function 
preg_match('/@(.*)/', $input, $output);
echo $output[1]; // it'll print "gmail.com"
```

- Documentation of function : preg_match()

Comment: That link has *absolutely nothing* to do with the question posted here. **Do not simply link to your website like this**, or you will find your posts being deleted as spam. I am removing the link for you.

Comment: I know it has nothing to do with the question but link contains very tough example so think It'll be useful to others...Ok I'll take care o f it next time. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this regular expression:

```
(?<=([\w-\.]@))((?:[\w]+\.)+)([a-zA-Z]{2,4})
```

Comment: (?<=([\w-\.]@))((?:[\w]+\.)+)([a-zA-Z]{2,4})

Answer (score 0):

```
(@)(\w+\-|\w+)+(\.)
```

I am no expert but the above expression is what you need to grab the domain from an e-mail, at least as far as I can tell.

The problem is as pointed out that you grab not only the domain but the "@" and ".". To access the domain name in regex you use "$2"and to preserve the "@" and ".", you could use an expression like:

```
$1newdomain$3
```

http://www.regexr.com/

The site above is a good place to try regex to see how and if it works.

Answer (score 0):

*Another shorter example is  **`@([\w.-]+)\.`***

*https://regex101.com/r/gmOH52/2*