# PHP find string within known characters

Tags: php, preg-match, strstr

please check the following:

```
$email  = 'name@example.com';
$domain = strstr($email, '@');
echo $domain; // prints @example.com
```

Is there a way I can return @example without the .com?

So, basically I need to search a string for a set of characters which i DON'T know, which exist between a set of charaters I DO know.

So, in the following I want to return "dog":

$string = "I used to have a pet dog named spot";

I can get the last section of the string using:

```
$pet_type = strstr($string, 'pet ');
```

Is this possible?

Comment: are you expecting any dots between the `@` and `.com`?

Comment: This might be helpful

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1487789/regular-expression-for-domain-from-email-address

Comment: `explode` > `preg_match` when applicable.

Comment: When applicable, yes. But 2 explodes to get a domain, that's when your code starts to get messy and it explodes in the toilet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

or use 2 times explode

```
$email  = 'name@example.com';
        $email  = explode( '@', $email);
        $email = explode('.', $email[1]);

        $email = $email[0];
        echo $email;
```

returns:  example

Answer (score 1):

You answer the question yourself in the tags. Using [regex/preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) you can look for patterns and extract values that match.

[Here's an introduction](http://webcheatsheet.com/php/regular_expressions.php) on regular expressions, it can look quite daunting but don't be sacred, it's quite logical :)

For your example with the domain, you could do something like this:

```
preg_match("@[^\.]+", $email, $matches);
$domain = $matches[0];
```

Comment: Which would be faster, though...finding the substring beginning as position *x* and ending after length *y*, or searching for a regular expression?

Comment: I believe regexes are quite fast. In your solution you need to be sure of the '.com' extension too, but that might not be a problem for the OP.

Comment: This regex *would* cause a problem in the case of a subdomain (i.e. mike@john.doe.org)

Answer (score 0):

Try `substr()` combined with `strpos()`

```
$start = strpos($email, '@');
$length = strpos($email, '.com') - $start;
$domain = substr($email, $start, $length);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$email = 'name@host.com';
$at_pos = strpos($email, '@');
$dot_pos = strpos($email,'.');
$domain_length = $dot_pos - $at_pos;
$domain = substr($email,$at_pos,$domain_length);
echo $domain;
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this a lot because it makes regular exprasions a lot simpler.
you can add ^ to a a range to invert it. [^aeiou] is th range of ALL characters but a, e, i, o und u.

For your example try

```
@[^\.]+
```

This will match "@example".

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
$str = '';
$email  = 'name@example.com';
$domain = strstr($email, '@');
$domain = str_split($domain);
foreach($domain as $split){
$str .= $split;
if($split == '.'){
break;
}
}
echo $str; // prints @example
```

or:

```
$email  = 'name@example.com';
$email = strstr($email, '@');
$email = explode(".", $domain);
echo $email[0]; // prints @example
```

Answer (score 0):

You need **regular expressions**.

```
preg_match('/@(\w+)\.com/', $email, $match);
$domain = $match[1];
```

See : http://www.php.net/manual/fr/book.pcre.php

Basically, in the `preg_match()` call, I'm testing if the string `$email` has the following sequence : an at symbol, then any positive number of word characters captured in a group using parentheses (`(\w+)`), then a dot (escaped : `\.`) and finally, `com`. If the match succeeds, the capture groups are put in the `$match` array and may be retrieved using their left-to-right position index.

The matching pattern can be improved depending on the type of characters you are expecting in your input. Overall REGEXes are slower than simple string replacements but much, much more powerful. It's worth learning how they work.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match('/\@([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)?/', 'test@site-test.com', $matches);

Array ( [0] => @site [1] => site )
```

`$matches[0]` is what you want to use.