# JavaScript regular expression for emails with fixed '@abc.com'

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs, validation, email

I need to validations in place for my Angular app on an email field. The restrictions are:
1. The email should be of valid format (Angular's built in validators would take care of this)
2. The email should have a fixed '@abc.com' part. The field should error out in case someone enters another domain.

I'm thinking I should use ng-pattern, but am not sure how to go forward with it. TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/^[-_A-Za-z0-9\.]+@abc\.com$/g
```

Quantifiers :

`+` Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]

`-_` a single character in the list -_ literally

`A-Z` a single character in the range between A and Z (case sensitive)

`a-z` a single character in the range between a and z (case sensitive)

`0-9` a single character in the range between 0 and 9

`@abc` matches the characters @abc literally (case sensitive)

`\.` matches the character . literally

`com` matches the characters com literally (case sensitive)
`$` assert position at end of the string

`g` modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression is quite heavy machinery for this purpose. Just split the string containing the email address at the `@` character, and take the second half. (An email address is guaranteed to contain only one `@` character.)

But if anyway you want to use it:

```
@(.*)$
```

This will match with the `@`, then capture everything up until the end of input ($)

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1487789/regular-expression-for-domain-from-email-address)